# Forget Password email not working laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am using users table column name (EMAIL,PASSWORD).if i am changing to column name(email) as small letters  is working fine. To Change column name(EMAIL) as caps is not working give me any suggestion. i am able to login but forget password is not working. please give any suggestion

my function in controller:

```
 public function postEmail(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, array('email' => 'required|email'));
    $response = $this->passwords->sendResetLink($request->only('EMAIL'), function ($m) {
        $m->subject($this->getEmailSubject());
    });
    switch ($response) {
        case PasswordBroker::RESET_LINK_SENT:
            return redirect()->back()->with('status', trans($response));
        case PasswordBroker::INVALID_USER:
            return redirect()->back()->withErrors(array('email' => trans($response)));
    }
}
```

I am getting this error in the page:

```
 QueryException in Connection.php line 624:
  SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'email' cannot be  null (SQL: insert into `password_resets` (`email`, `token`,`created_at`) 
  values (, 5d2b40143e084824402984c81cdfaa64264328bdc9c6d73cf80e1a1aa773d0cc, 2016-07-29 09:52:40))
```

Answer (score 1):

Email field in your form is called **EMAIL** so your validation will fail, as it checks for existence of **email** field in the request.

For the start, replace

```
$this->validate($request, array('email' => 'required|email'));
```

with

```
$this->validate($request, array('EMAIL' => 'required|email'));
```

and let me know if it already works or there are some other errors and I'll update the answer with next steps. Be sure to post the error you're getting.

In order to store password reset tokens you need to tell Laravel how to retrieve user's email. You can do that by adding the following method to your **User** model:

```
public function getEmailForPasswordReset()
{
    return $this->EMAIL;
}
```

Comment: this the error I am getting..                                                                                                         QueryException in Connection.php line 624:
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'email' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `password_resets` (`email`, `token`, `created_at`) values (, 5d2b40143e084824402984c81cdfaa64264328bdc9c6d73cf80e1a1aa773d0cc, 2016-07-29 09:52:40))